# "Shiny App" Uploads file -> Does Something -> Outputs file

Tags: r, web-scraping, shiny

### I am trying to write my first Shiny App that reads a PDF file, extracts tables and saves it into Excel document.

I am failing to produce suitable code. So far I have:
1) For UI

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(   
        titlePanel("CMM Report"),      
        sidebarPanel(
               fileInput("file", "Upload Report")
     ),

     downloadButton("dl", "Download")

))
```

2) For Server

```
library(shiny)
library (tabulizer)
library(writexl) 

shinyServer(function(input, output) {       
    data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    file1 <- ExtractTable (file1)        
})
## Download
output$dl <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() { "ae.xlsx"}, 
  content = function(file) {write_xlsx(data, path = file)}  
)    
})
```

I am not sure If I need to put the code for extracting table in a function and where to call the function, to make it work.  Any help REALLY appreciated.
The data file of the example is from here
report <- "http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf"

### Function to extract data

```
ExtractTable <- function (report){
  lst <- extract_tables(report, encoding="UTF-8") 

  # Delete blank columns
  lst[[1]] <- lst[[1]][, -3]
  lst[[2]] <- lst[[2]][, -4]

  # Bind the list elements 
  table <- do.call(rbind, lst)
  table <- as.data.frame(table[c(2:37, 40:nrow(table)), ],
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # ...w/o obsolete rows

  # Take over colnames, cache rownames to vector
  colnames(table) <- table[1, ]
  rn <- table[2:71, 1]
  table <- table[-1,-1] # and bounce them out of the table

  #  Coerce to numeric 
  table <- as.data.frame(apply(table[1:70,1:10], 2, 
                               function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
  rownames(table) <- rn 

  return(table)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {       
    data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    ExtractTable(file1$datapath) # $datapath was missing       
})
## Download
output$dl <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() { "ae.xlsx"}, 
  content = function(file) {write_xlsx(data(), path = file)} # parentheses () were missing
)    
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately with that code I get:

Warning: Error in path.expand: invalid 'path' argument
  [No stack trace available]
Warning: Error in write_xlsx: Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames
  [No stack trace available]

I tried a simpler example substituting the ExtractFunction for:  DOSOMETHING <- function (df){head(df)} 

and inputting a csv file. I get the same result.  :-(

All I want for the App is to 1) Upload a file  2) do something with it 3) allow the user to save it as excel (with dataframes saved in multiple worksheets)

Comment: It doesn't even seem to work for just upload a csv file and save it to excel.  :(  
Warning: Error in write_xlsx: Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames
  [No stack trace available]

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   
data <- reactive({
  file1 <- input$file
   if(is.null(file1)){return()}
  
 # DOSOMETHING(file1$datapath) 
})


## Download
output$dl <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() { "ae.xlsx"}, 
  content = function(file) {write_xlsx(data , path = file)}
)


})

Comment: @GustavoAEscobar-Palafox Have you put the parentheses: `write_xlsx(data() , path = file)` (`data()`, not `data`) ?

Comment: I tried with and without paréntesis.  If I write df = mtcars and then write df instead of data() in the write_xlsx  I managed to output the mtcars as excel.  But I haven't been able to simply read a csv file store it in a variable and output it as excel :(